# Horizontal dotplot in R

Tags: r

Is it possible to create a dotplot - dotchart() - in R with a horizontal orientation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `dotplot` from the `lattice` package, there is an argument named `horizontal` that controls direction.

```
dotplot(VADeaths, main = "Death Rates in Virginia - 1940", horizontal = FALSE)
dotplot(VADeaths, main = "Death Rates in Virginia - 1940", horizontal = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear to me what you mean by horizontal, but you might compare the effect of

```
dotchart(VADeaths, main = "Death Rates in Virginia - 1940")
```

and its transpose

```
dotchart(t(VADeaths), main = "Death Rates in Virginia - 1940")
```

Comment: Instead, I think the OP wants to have the plot drawn so that one interprets differences by the height up the y-axis rather than the distance across the x-axis.